# Получить объект по ForeignKey во втором уровне вложенности

Tags: django, python-3.8

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()

class User(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()

class List(models.Model)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Item(models.Model)
 name = models.CharField()
 list = models.ForeignKey(List)
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

views.py

```
class ListView(View)
  def get(self, request, pk)
    list = List.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, "list.html", {"list" : list})
```

list.html

```
{% for item in list.item_set.all %}
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.user.name }} - ??
  {{ item.product.name }} - ??
{% endfor %}
```

Как получить user.name и product.name?

**Пробовал:**

1. `{% item.user_set.first.name %}` - не работает
2. `{% for user in item.user_set.all %}{{ user.name }}{% endfor %}` - не работает
3. Метод модели

   ```
   def get_user(self): 
       self.user_ser.get() #не работает
   ```

Перерыл весь google и en.stackoverflow не могу найти ответ(

Comment: должно работать `{% for item in list.item_set.all %}
  {{ item.name }}
  {{ item.user.name }} 
  {{ item.product.name }}
{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

```
class ListView(View)
  def get(self, request, pk)
    list = User.objects.get(id=pk) #изменил модель
    return render(request, "list.html", {"list" : list})
```

К связанным моделям обращаются через ключевое слово _set читайте официальную документацию

```
{% for a in list %}
    <h1>{{a.name}}</h1>
        {% for b in a.list_set.all %}
            <ul>{{b.user}}</ul>
                    {% for c in b.item_set.all %}
                        <li>{{c.product}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Я же написал в конце какие варианты пробывал. 
Ваш вариант там присутствует. Так не работает(

Comment: @Ruslan изменения во views.py видел? Да и мойт ответ отличается от того что пробовал ты

Comment: @Ruslan вот ответ на такой же вопрос .https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081296/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85/1082404#1082404
только там выводится не спомощь класса listview

Comment: Извини, но если бы мне надо было поменять модель, я бы ее сам поменял. Я получаю объект List. Дальше из через _set получаю все Item которые принадлежат к этому List. У Item есть Product и User, мне нужно получить имена обоих.

Comment: это не тот ответ. Получить из родителя дочек и дочек у этих дочек это легко. Про это в офф документации хорошо написано. А вот как получить данные родителя из дочки-дочки вот этого нету ни где.